# Passing arguments by address, why &(*v) is valid?

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass function argument by address with C programming to avoid creating copy.

I'm doing it like that:

```
void change(int *v)
{
   (*v) =  (*v) + 1;
}

void value(int *v)
{
    printf("%i\n", *v);

    change(v);

    printf("%i\n", *v);

    change(&(*v));

    printf("%i\n", *v);
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 89;
    value(&x);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

**89**
**90**
**91**

Can someone please explain to me why **v** and **&(*v)** are both valid as an argument for change?

I was expecting that only v will be the correct and valid argument...

Comment: Why would "the address of the thing the pointer is pointing to" not be a valid way to say "the value of the pointer"?

Comment: Your expectations don't have much in common with C. Could you elaborate on them so it's possible to understand what your question is beyond "I need a basic pointer tutorial"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `*v` is legal then `&*v` is equivalent to `v`. `&` is the inverse of `*`.

```
int *v = &x;

v;        // address of x
*v;       // x
&*v;      // address of x
```

Comment: And `*&v;    // address of x` too :)

Comment: Re “`&*v` is equivalent to `v`”: This is inadequate because the question asks about `&(*v)`, not `&*v`. Normally, when used in an expression, `*v` would be converted from an lvalue to a value, by C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, and then `&` could not be applied to it. But there is a special rule for parentheses, in 6.5.1 5, which prevents this. A full answer needs to explain that. For example, `&(*v)` is valid but `&(0, *v)` is not.

Comment: I prefer to avoid language pedantry in my answers to beginner-level questions. I don't think any of that is important or necessary.

Comment: An answer that *teaches* a concept should explain things in simple, easy to understand terms. It shouldn't get tangled up with exceptions and minutiae. This is different from *reference* material like the C standard which must document all of the rules in detail. It's poor pedagogy to overwhelm a learner with advanced information that isn't relevant day-to-day (such as the comma operator or lvalues).

Comment: While the special rules about parentheses may be a lot to throw at a beginner, it is nonetheless wrong to answer for `&*v` when the question asks about `&(*v)`. The answer should at least assert that `&(*v)` is equivalent to `v`, not that `&*v` is equivalent to `v`. Then, even it is not presenting all the rules involved, it is at least talking about the thing that was asked about instead of something different.

Comment: `*&v` and `*(&v)` are the same thing. `&(0, *v)` is invalid because of the comma operator, not the parentheses. Please, write your own answer if you think mine's inadequate. I'm happy with it as is.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when you pass `&x` to function `value`, this is what you got:

```
v=&x
*v = x 
&(*v)=&x
```

so passing either  `v` or `&(*v)` to function `change` are both valid with the same meaning of passing `&x` to function `change`.